# Compute Module 3+, using SD card on sd1

Tags: sd-card, compute-module

I have a custom designed board using the compute module 3+, booting from the EMMC with an SD card interface connected to GPIO 34-39.  From what I've read elsewhere the only thing I need to do is to setup the sdio [overlay](https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux/blob/rpi-4.19.y/arch/arm/boot/dts/overlays/sdio-overlay.dts) in /boot/config.txt:

```
dtoverlay=sdio,poll_once=0,gpios_34_39=1
```

The output of `vcdbg log msg` indicates the overlay was loaded correctly however the output of `dmesg` contains:

```
mmc1: card never left busy state
mmc1: error -110 whilst initialising SD card
```

Is there something more or different that I should be doing to get the SD card interface to work?  Its possible that the issue is with the connections on the custom board however I want to make sure I am doing everything correctly from the software side before I go back to the engineers at the board house.

**UPDATE**
It turns out the SD card interface wasn't getting power due to a hardware issue however I am still unable to get the SD card to work, the error message has changed to:

```
mmc1: host does not support reading read-only switch, assuming write-enable
mmc1: error -110 whilst initialising SD card
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get it working by adding `sdio_overclock=25` to the dtoverlay line to set the clock speed to 25mhz.  That said, I am not sure if this is specific to the interface on the board, the SD card I was testing with, a [Samsung 32GB EVO Select](https://smile.amazon.com/gp/product/B06XWN9Q99/), or the compute module itself but I would have thought this is something that would be auto-detected...

To complete the answer, I was able to get it to work by adding this to /boot/config.txt:

```
dtoverlay=sdio,sdio_overclock=25,poll_once=0,gpios_34_39=1
```